# Summing up data in x intervals in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a problem that looks at trade data that looks like the following.
InstrumentId TradeDate Quantity Price TransactionTime
ESH1    2/24/2021   1   3859    2:05 AM
ESH1    2/24/2021   1   3865.5  2:10 AM
ESH1    2/24/2021   1   3865.5  2:10 AM
ESH1    2/24/2021   1   3866    2:15 AM
ESH1    2/24/2021   1   3866    2:15 AM
ESH1    2/24/2021   1   3866    2:15 AM
NQH1    2/24/2021   1   13137.2 2:20 AM
ESH1    2/24/2021   2   3867.25 2:20 AM
NQH1    2/24/2021   1   13132.2 2:21 AM
NQH1    2/24/2021   1   13127.2 2:22 AM
ESH1    2/24/2021   3   3865.5  2:25 AM
HGH1    2/24/2021   1   418.3   2:25 AM
NQH1    2/24/2021   1   13128   2:25 AM
NQH1    2/24/2021   1   13124   2:26 AM
ESH1    2/24/2021   4   3866.5  2:30 AM
HGH1    2/24/2021   1   418.3   2:30 AM
NQH1    2/24/2021   1   13130   2:30 AM

I'm trying to find out the net position for each InstrumentId at every 5 minute interval and I'm not sure how to go about it. I've looked and df.rolling and df.resample() but I can't figure out how to apply it to this problem.

The result should look something like:
InstrumentId Time Net Position
ESH1    2:05 AM 1
NQH1    2:05 AM 0
HGH1    2:05 AM 0
ESH1    2:10 AM 3
NQH1    2:10 AM 0
HGH1    2:10 AM 0
ESH1    2:15 AM 6
NQH1    2:15 AM 0
HGH1    2:15 AM 0
ESH1    2:20 AM 8
NQH1    2:20 AM 1
HGH1    2:20 AM 0
ESH1    2:25 AM 11
NQH1    2:25 AM 4
HGH1    2:25 AM 1
ESH1    2:30 AM 15
NQH1    2:30 AM 6
HGH1    2:30 AM 2

Comment: post your data as text,  most obvious answer is `resample()`

Comment: Can you give a couple example rows of the output you're looking for?

Comment: Edited my post to have the sample data in text and added sample results